# Pasting with mouse-select in GNU Emacs

Tags: emacs, xemacs

There is an functionality in XEmacs that if the user selects a region with the mouse while holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, the selected region will be automatically pasted at the current cursor position.

In other words, if you need to quickly copy a short block of text from some open buffer to a new spot, you put the cursor there, and then do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-mouse-select and it works.

Unfortunately, I recently had to switch from XEmacs to GNU Emacs, and I'm looking to see if there is similar functionality there, or perhaps I could provide it with a custom module (I am very bad at Lisp, unfortunately).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You sure can, the functionality is bound to mouse button 3 if I'm not mistaken.
I assume so, because clicking my mousewheel yanks what I've copied at the cursor.

And Mousewheel == mouse button 3 in most cases.

1. Select using your mouse
2. With your mouse button down, hit control
3. Release your mouse button
4. Hit mouse button 3
5. Profit - selection yanked at your cursor

edit:

I found this on http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Mouse-Commands.html

- Mouse-1

  Move point to where you click (mouse-set-point).
- Drag-Mouse-1

  Activate the region around the text selected by dragging, and copy it
  to the kill ring (mouse-set-region).
- Mouse-2

  Yank the last killed text at the click position (mouse-yank-at-click).
- Mouse-3

  If the region is active, move the nearer end of the region to the click position; otherwise, set mark at the current value of point and point at the click position. Save the resulting region in the kill ring; on a second click, kill it (mouse-save-then-kill).

Comment: Has no effect for me. It seems my button3 works as a scroller, but I can't make it work as paste at all.

Also, the key mechanics I described for XEmacs is quite different (and it seems more convenient): Ctrl+mouse-select. Just making sure what I wrote was not misinterpreted...

Comment: which means you can't click the scroller? All the mice I've had the scroller could be clicked as well as scrolled forth and back.

Comment: When I'm at my workplace, clicking the scroller works as paste, but your instructions yield yanking new text at the place of the mouse button 3 click (as it would behave if nothing was done with the Ctrl key - just select with the mouse and then mouse-3 pastes).

When I'm at home, my mouse scroller scrolls ok, but when I click it, it does not work as paste at all. Not sure if something could be done about that, will find out, but what can I do to at least get the situation at my workplace (where scroller click registers as paste) resolved? thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Put the following in your init file (`.emacs`):

```
(require 'mouse-copy)
(global-set-key [C-down-mouse-1] 'mouse-drag-secondary-pasting)
```

Once you restart Emacs, it should work just like you're used to in XEmacs--hold down `Ctrl` and the left mouse button, select your text, and when you release the mouse the text will be inserted at your current cursor position.

Comment: @Stefan recommended mouse-copy as well but I couldn't find any information on it (I got a "Can't find library mouse-copy") when trying to find it in Emacs, and I had byte-compiled source code in my distribution; I finally figured out how to use it here: http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/emacs/emacs-51/emacs/lisp/mouse-copy.el

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use `mouse-copy.el` which comes with Emacs.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know Emacs that well -- how do I use it?

Comment: @gt6989b: I'd recommend you do `M-x find-library RET mouse-copy RET` and then read the text after `;;; Commentary:`.